# Data tables add update delete and edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

My question is about how can I edit, delete and add data in Datatables
[jsfiddle CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/wqoq4um0/9/)

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Result</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>End Time</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

```
$(document).ready(function (){
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/575cy",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "tId" }, 
        { "data": "description"}, 
        { "data": "rst" }, 
        { "data": "startDate" }, 
        { "data": "endDate"}
   ]        
});
```

});

1: In above link there is code by someone I want to know if it's possible to add, update and delete data.

2: I also want to know how update, delete and edit will change data on json page as well so after refresh or on reopening the page I see updated not the previous data.

EIDTED:: I also have a MySQL database using with servlet and JSP , java if anyone can help me find a solution on using datatables with that as well and edit and delete as well...

Hope I have cleared myself properly.